# nhibernate select n points in date range

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

So here's my situation:  I have two tables that contains statistics, one table for the statistic definitions, and a table for the statistic events.  Each row in the stats event table has a timestamp, a value, and a Reference to the statistic definition that it applies to, and each statistic definition has a collection of stat entries. (i.e. one to many)

My app allows a user to select a statistic definition and date range, and graphs the entries from the stat event table for the selected definition.  However, it's possible for the user to select a large date range, and this could result in a larger number of returned events than is necessary.

I'd like to return a subset of the data (n points) that's evenly distributed over the time range that the user selects.  My current (naive) implementation is the following:

```
var totalEntries = session.QueryOver<StatEvent>()
                          .Where(x => x.Date > start_date && x.Date < end_date && StatDef.Id == defn.Id)
                          .List()
int modFactor = (int) Math.Ceiling((double)totalEntries.Count/30);
var temp = totalEntries.Where((x, i) => i%modFactor == 0);
return temp.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
```

So I'm retrieving all of the records from the DB matching the date range and stat defn, then selecting 30 entries.

The problems with this approach are:

1) It's inefficient to get all of the entries from the DB, and then discard the ones that I don't want.

2) If the data is clumped (i.e. there are many records around a certain time, and not many records around another time) the selection will be weighted to where there is the most data.  This is not necessarily a bad thing, but I'd like my graphs to be prettier, and have evenly distributed data points.

So, does anyone know of a smart way to achieve the same result but in a more efficient manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest aggregating the values over a set of intervals, where the size of the interval is calculated as 1/30th of the selected date range.  The manner in which you aggregate will depend on the stats, but a naive implementation could just sum them or average them or get the max value.

Comment: This is a good idea, but my only concern is that if the user selects a very large date range (like a year, which is a valid thing to ask for) then I'd have to average over all of the entries in the range, and this risks slowing things down even more.

Comment: You can do the aggregate in the database query, using Projections.SqlGroupProjection (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801712/groupby-sqlfunction-on-queryover/10850296#10850296) and some MySql date function to group by the interval